# How to set region for an amazonS3 client?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am trying to implement file upload in a Java web application. When the user uploads a file through the UI, I want it to be stored in amazon amazon s3 storage.

Here is my code for the back-end:

```
@PostMapping("/upload-file")
public String saveFile(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("user", "psw");

    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

    String bucketName = "kfib";

    s3Client.createBucket(bucketName);

    s3Client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));


    ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
    md.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

//        md.set

```
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, name, inputStream, md).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, name));

        log.info("Url of the image:\n");
        log.info(s3Object.getObjectContent().getHttpRequest().getURI().toString());

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    log.info("upload called with post method...");

    return "redirect:/admin/posts";
}
```

I can upload to files if I upload them to the default region. However, I wish to store my files on another server. I have a bucket in an EU region, if I try to upload something there with the above code, I get the following error code:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1' (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed; Request ID: 8EF630B5F0224C4F)
```

It seems this line

```
s3Client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));
```

doesn't have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AmazonS3Client.setRegion()` is deprecated. Didn't you try to use `AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(String)`? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#setRegion-java.lang.String-

Comment: I am quite possibly mistaken, given the standard tediousness of Java, but `s3Client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));` seems kind of... redundant. Is this not simply `s3Client.setRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)`;

Comment: Sorry @rpuch I apparently spent > 5 minutes writing my comment, which is somewhat redundant itself, in light of yours... Your question seems better than mine.

Comment: I presume you replaced the AccessKey / SecretKey values that are passed to BasicAWSCredentials in your code above for security, and are not really passing in a username and password? It's worth checking that they are correct as I've had a misleading error like this calling AmazonS3Client.headBucket() when the access key or secret key are invalid.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue, but the following worked for me-

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Comment: What should I use if I had this before: `AmazonS3Client(AnonymousAWSCredentials())` ?

Answer (score 2):

For Global bucket access

you can set  `withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled` flag to true

like

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: Unfortunately SDK v2 does not have this.